# Do you need identification to take the ferry from Belfast to Liverpool?

Tags: uk, paperwork, ferries, northern-ireland, liverpool

When taking the ferry from Belfast to Liverpool do you need identification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes you will need some form of identification, even if you are British or Irish (counterintuitively, as evidence of this fact, so that you then don't legally need identification), but it doesn't necessarily need to be photo ID such as a passport.

The precise rules will depend on your carrier, but to quote from the [Stena Line FAQ](https://www.stenaline.co.uk/faqs/passports-and-visas/im-a-british-irish-citizen-do-i-need-a-passport-to-travel):

> **I’M A BRITISH / IRISH CITIZEN. DO I NEED A PASSPORT TO TRAVEL?**
>
> British or Irish citizens travelling on our Irish Sea routes do not need a passport to travel to Britain or Ireland but are advised to take a form of identity. A driving licence, citizenship card or utility bill will usually suffice. A birth certificate will provide adequate proof of identity for your child to travel on our sailings.

Comment: That information seems to be referring to travel to the Republic of Ireland, but Liverpool to NI might be less strict because it's not an international journey.

Comment: It refers to "Irish Sea routes" which will cover both the Republic and NI?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answer is essentially wrong. British and Irish citizens don't need a passport to travel between each others' countries but, as you say, they do need some way of proving that they're British or Irish, which often ends up being a passport. But this is a ferry from Northern Ireland to England. This is an entirely domestic journey within the UK, just like taking a train from England to Scotland.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Not necessarily. I have experienced random id checks on Stena Line's routes in Scandinavia, where there is also no official requirement to carry a passport. The reason is the same why many airlines check identification (also on domestic flights), that they want to make sure that the name on the ticket matches with the passenger.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm just quoting the rules they present, I don't make them. When travelling in China you even need ID for the trains.

Comment: @origimbo You're not "just" quoting the rules: your answer begins with two paragraphs of your own text. That text implies a context where national borders are being crossed and people need to prove their citizenship to prove that they're eligible for passport-free travel. But this is not a journey that crosses national borders: it is a domestic journey within the UK.

Comment: The UK is a union of four countries. Wikipedia gives NI the status of "Country (constituent unit)." This journey crosses a country border, but being part of a Union there are legal derogations in place to reduce/remove checks?

Comment: @Ben If it's the legal side which interests you, this is the wrong site. Having said that https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/legal_basis_for_in_country_passe might be a reasonable resource to start from on that front.